# Is there a ip address for adsl modem?

Tags: networking, lan

I am surfing the web this way:isp  telephoneline  >  separator > adsl modem > route > my pc .

In my pc :
ifconfig
inet addr:192.168.1.100
It is my intranet ip address.

In the admin interface of route
To input 192.168.1.1  in firefox :
WAN
MAC：xxxx
IP address：153.0.33.28     PPPoE
net mask：255.255.255.255

gateway：153.0.32.1
DNS server：114.114.114.114 223.5.5.5
LAN
MAC address：yyyy
IP address：192.168.1.1
netmask：255.255.255.0
DHCP：active

Is there a modem ip for my local net?What is?

Comment: NOTE: Revealing your MAC address isn't going to expose you to much more in terms of 'attack vector' on your LAN NIC.  In any case, you already SEE the IP address there, under the WAN information.  What more are you looking for?

Comment: Does my adsl modem have ip address?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `tracepath` from the `iputils-tracepath` package. It will tell you the IP address and DNS name of every system between you and the parameter. Read `man tracepath`.

```
$ tracepath slashdot.org
 1?: [LOCALHOST]                                         pmtu 1492
 1:  sparky                                                0.711ms 
 1:  sparky                                                0.664ms 
 2:  dsl-173-216-5-1.tor.primus.ca                        30.202ms 
 3:  10.201.117.10                                        31.766ms asymm  5 
 4:  as6407.xe-3-3-3.cr1.tor1.ca.as4436.gtt.net           30.986ms 
 5:  xe-3-3-3.cr1.tor1.ca.as4436.gtt.net                 218.751ms asymm  7 
 6:  be2436.ccr21.alb02.atlas.cogentco.com               227.761ms 
 7:  be2106.ccr41.jfk02.atlas.cogentco.com               241.215ms 
 8:  be2629.rcr23.jfk01.atlas.cogentco.com               145.655ms 
 9:  das5-v3029.ch3.savvis.net                           226.881ms asymm 11 
10:  64.27.160.198                                       224.792ms asymm 13 
11:  cr1-te-0-1-0-1.chd.savvis.net                       147.527ms 
12:  hr3-xe-8-0-0.elkgrovech3.savvis.net                 244.807ms asymm 11 
13:  hr3-xe-8-0-0.elkgrovech3.savvis.net                 249.768ms asymm 11 
14:  64.27.160.194                                       155.325ms asymm 13 
15:  slashdot.org                                        159.494ms reached
     Resume: pmtu 1492 hops 15 back 14
```

You will get different results, of course.